# Off-center hinge construction

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms

I want to build a monitor supporting arm for three monitors besides each other. The outer monitors shall be able to swivel forward to reduce size of the whole thing when not in use. My problem's that I have no idea how to design the hinge - the outer monitors should rotate around their inner forward vertical edge, but I cannot put a hinge there, because the monitors have to be as close to each other as possible.

I'm looking for something I can put into the supporting arm behind the monitors that acts like a hinge at the front (outside the arm itself)... how to do this?

Comment: If you provide a diagram, I can help ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use something like they use on boats and planes for the doors.
It's called a pantograph hinge.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use offset hinges at the top and bottom of the screen. That way you can still have the hing axis where you want it.

The other option is a multibar linkage. Though designing that requires a bit more intuition.